# How can I compare DateTime.Now with MySQL DATETIME format?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datetime, compare

Hello guys I have a MySQL database with some `DATETIME` values stored. I want to compare those values in C# with the `DateTime.Now` attribute. I just want to write:

> if (DateTime.Now.ToString() < MySQL fetched DATETIME + 3 hours)

Thanks for all your tips

Answer (score 2):

Do *not* compare your DateTime values with their string representations. You should compare them exactly as their values.

Instead;

1. Use [`MySqlDataReader`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm) or any other structure to get the values from your database.
2. Use [`GetDateTime(int)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_GetDateTime.htm) method to get relevant Datetime value.

And compare them like

```
if(DateTime.Now < fetchedDateTime.AddHours(3))
```

By the way, you should be aware of [the case against `DateTime.Now`](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).